# accessing the same info from different places?

Tags: usability, information-architecture, mobile-application

I am working on a high level flow for a mobile app and I have created two launch points that renders the same screen one from the details screen of the primary information and the other from the summary screen. I have attached the flow, will this create confusion? Any suggestion/comments would help.[image]

Comment: I don't mind if you need to blur the contents, but some labels would be great. Presuming left = start; top = summary; bottom = details; and right = more details?

Answer (score 2):

It's not uncommon to access the same content (view or screen) from different places. The hierarchical model have been great organizing content but lacked the ability to find related content. That's the idea of faceted navigation pattern. You don’t have to go back to the start screen to access another related screen in a different branch of the hierarchy.

[image]

Image from [Designing for Discovery with Faceted Navigation](http://experiencinginformation.wordpress.com/workshops/past-workshops/11-april-2013-ux-london-discovery-with-faceted-navigation/), UX London 2013

More to read: [Design Patterns: Faceted Navigation](http://alistapart.com/article/design-patterns-faceted-navigation)